# Scroll images right to left using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, infinite-scroll

I am looking to scroll images from right to left with hover holding images. Marquee is obsolete. I tried this but the image is not scrolling.

I don't have a clue where to start. I googled it but is not working for me.

I am trying to achieve it through the below code. I need images to auto scroll in an infinite loop RTL. Any help will be appreciated. [Scroll right to left](http://jsbin.com/emexug/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

```
$('a').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#hello').stop().animate({
        scrollLeft: $(this).index() * $('#hello').width()
    }, 5700);
});
```

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. Do you mean that you want to make your gallery slide from right to left when you mouse over the images?

Comment: yes ...i am looking for that kept text instead of image for keeping it simple.thanks

Comment: Then you should consider using `mouseenter` event on `#hello` instead of using click event on a tag. Still confused about what you want to achieve, if you want the images/text auto slide, then why you want it to happen when hovering on the images/text?

Comment: looking for images to slide.image here http://prntscr.com/lmzdsd   and code here http://jsbin.com/emexug/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: @Amit are you looking for an image slider?

Comment: I think an image slider will do fine. For example:
http://wowslider.com/rq/html-fade-slideshow-transition-on-mouse-hover-7X.html

Comment: i need three image in one frame